# Using ng-click in a ng-repeat with data

Tags: angularjs, pug

I want to use data from the ng-repeat in a ng-click, but it seems not to be filled with the correct data. What I'm doing wrong here?

```
a.btn.btn-sm.btn-light-blue(ng-href='', ng-click='filter_category="{{collection}}"', ng-repeat='collection in collectionCategory')
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `"{{}}"` like this :

```
a.btn.btn-sm.btn-light-blue(ng-href='', ng-click='filter_category=collection', ng-repeat='collection in collectionCategory')
```

Comment: The code will be rendered as ng-click='filter_category=category', so it doesn't contain the value of {{collection}}

Comment: give it a try @NVO

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `collection` object before exwcution of `ng-repeat`.

For Ex.

```
<div ng-repeat="'collection in collectionCategory'" >
   <button ng-click='filter_category="{{collection}}"'> click </button>
</div>
```